# How do I make an ajax request to a CakePHP plugin controller?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP's users plugin, and I've made an ajax function inside the UsersController.php file. The only problem is, when I call it, it keeps telling me the file doesn't exist because it's looking for the UsersController in the app\Controller file, instead of where it's located in the app\Plugin\Users\Controller location.

How can I specify that I'm referring to this location instead of the other?

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url:  '/Users/Users/ajax/validateEmail/json',
            data: {
                email : email
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success:
                function(response) {
                    if(response){
                        $("#emailError").append("<p class='text-danger'>This email is already in use.</p>");
                    }
                },
            error:
                function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
        });
```

The error:

```
Missing Controller

Error: UsersController could not be found.

Error: Create the class UsersController below in file: app\Controller\UsersController.php

<?phpclass UsersController extends AppController {}
Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\missing_controller.ctp
```

I'm calling the function from the view inside the Users plugin, so I figured I would call the controller as I normally would when using a view outside the plugin. This is incorrect.

The Users Controller does exist, it's just inside of the app\Plugin\Users\Controller directory instead. Changing my URL to specify does not work.

Comment: `/users/users/ajax/...` http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#plugin-tips

Comment: I have tried this as well, and it still gives me the 'missing controller' error as before.

Comment: Would be good if you'd mention all the things that you've already tried. What does your routes configuration look like? Have you made sure that the plugin is actually [**loaded**](https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/2.1.0/Docs/Documentation/Routing.md)? And are you including its routes config? Also you can check `Router::url(array('plugin' => 'users', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'ajax'));` to see if it matches a route to your plugin at all, and if so, what the proper URL should look like (and while you're at it you could use the router instead of hard-coding the URL in your view).